# C# WPF вытащить компонент из xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть некое окно с разметкой Main.xaml, и есть некий файл с отдельно свёрстанным элементом(пусть будет Button.xaml) вот с такой начинкой

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Border >
        <Label Content="Text"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

(это весь xaml файл)

Как мне подцепить этот элемент и положить его в какой либо контейнер?

Comment: Зачем вам это понадобилась? Почему просто не использовать шаблоны?

Comment: Я хочу создать расширяемое приложение, в котором Вьюхи можно писать отдельно от проекта, без перекомпиляции самого проекта

Comment: Ну а почему не хранить их в скомпилированных сборках, а не в голых xaml-файлах?

Comment: Потому что они будут собираться в сборки во время работы основной программ (это проект в учебных целях, для познания рефлексии)
Я хочу создать "Проект с под-проектами" который будет динамически подгружать заселекченный под-проект, и выводить его вёрстку в основное окно.

Comment: А под-проект должен будет представляться в папочке с заданной базовой структурой, главной вьюхой и входной точкой под-приложения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так, если предполагается, что Button.xaml лежит в каталоге с программой и его нужно загрузить во время выполнения:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UIElement xaml = (UIElement)LoadXaml("Button.xaml");
            grid.Children.Add(xaml);
        }

        public static object LoadXaml(string path)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
            using (sr)
            {
                object el = XamlReader.Load(sr.BaseStream);
                return el;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но XAML-файл, загруженный таким образом, не может содержать ссылок на методы (обработчики событий), определенные в коде. Допустим только чистый XAML.

Comment: Хм, попробую  тогда подцепить обработчики при помощи рефлексии, надеюсь получится, благодарю!